# Does Notepad++ support the European number 7?

Tags: notepad++, truetype-fonts, handwriting

Is it possible to type the European number 7 (i.e. the number 7 with a slash through it) on Notepad++. I have tried downloading fonts to Windows 10 but the 7 never gets reproduced with a slash.

Comment: I have never seen any font (even in printed books) where number 7 is represented with a slash. To my knowledge and experience (and I'm an European), that form is and has been used in handwriting only.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What do you mean by "slash"? Like a hyphen in the middle? Show a picture if ou mean something else.

Comment: It seems there are such images for graphic design, as https://www.etsy.com/dk-en/listing/818925120/ink-free-handwriting-font-regular-style

Comment: Also, do you want it just for yourself so that all 7s in random text files look like that or do you want to actually use a character similar to that? I assume the 1st since you mentioned fonts, but the question is so inspecific that it's hard to answer any accurately.

Comment: Are you talking about [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Hand_Written_7.svg) ? It could be view only with specific fonts.

Comment: Given what you will need to get it working, consider why you want to do this, as this most likely is going to mean that it will only work on your computer.

Answer (score 2):

You could install a font that has this style of 7 with a horizontal bar. A quick search for handwriting-style fonts shows a few, e.g. this free one -- https://www.fontriver.com/font/rylees_handwriting/

This question got me curious though, and I found this article interesting -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tironian_notes -- but the characters seem poorly supported in mainstream fonts.

Comment: I don't see any strike `7` in your links.

Comment: The sample shown of the font is only letters so there is no 7 of any kind on display. Try typing a 7 in the sample box, or just search for some other handwriting fonts...